# ¿Cuál es el origen de "piscolabis"?

Tags: etimología

En otro día usé la palabra *piscolabis* en una frase, no es una palabra que utilice habitualmente pero me parece graciosa y la intención al decirla era humorística.

Me puse a pensar de donde vendría y no se me ocurría nada, no encontraba palabras similares o que compartieran la misma raíz para aventurar alguna teoría.

En el DLE, donde la marca como de origen incierto, he visto que tiene tres definiciones, yo solo conocía la segunda:

> [**piscolabis**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TCjCzM1)
>
> ```
> De or. inc.
> ```
>
> **1.** m. En algunos juegos de naipes, como el tresillo, acción de echar un triunfo superior al que ya está en la mesa, con lo cual se gana
> baza.
>
> **2.** m. coloq. Ligera refacción que se toma, no tanto por necesidad como por ocasión o por regalo.
>
> **3.** m. *Méx*. **dinero** (‖ moneda corriente).

Pues la pregunta es simplemente, ¿de dónde viene esta palabra?

Comment: Hubo un tiempo en el que estaba convencido de que la palabra era "psicolabis".

Comment: ¿No nos vas a dar el contexto y la frase?  Yo no conocía esta palabra para nada.  Las definiciones no me dan lo humorístico que mencionaste.

Comment: @aparente001 la frase era algo así como: "A ver cuando quedamos y tomamos un piscolabis". No tiene nada de humorístico es sí misma, solo que es una palabra poco frecuente y un poco extraña y me resulta graciosa.

Comment: Gracias, blonfu, acabo de darme cuenta que entendí mal la definición 2 en la pregunta!  (Yo solo conocía la última definición de *refacción* en DLE [7. f. Hond. y Méx. recambio (‖ pieza para sustituir a otra igual). Llanta de refacción.].  Ahora aprendí [1. f. Alimento moderado que se toma para reparar las fuerzas.].)

Comment: *refacción* es una palabra que no conocia hasta que la he visto en esta definición.

Answer (score 6):

Aunque Corominas cita su origen en 1884, hay casos en la hemeroteca bastante anteriores:

> *[...] yo me figuro que vd. debe alimentarse con cantáridas , ó con cornetillas, ó albóndigas de la Ñora, que diz le sobra al diablo con una para desayuno, echándose en seguida su piscolabis de ácido sulfúrico para que no se indigeste [...].*
>
> **Atalaya de La Mancha en Madrid.** 15/7/1814, [página 1](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0004186002&page=1&lang=es).

Sobre su origen, el diccionario de la RAE de 1884 dice que es "de formación caprichosa" antes de pasar al "de origen incierto". Sobre dicha "formación caprichosa", el citado Corominas dice:

> [...] formación burlesca seudo-latina, probablemente derivada de *pizca*; sentido: 'comerás un pedacito de algo'; a imitación de futuros como *cibabis*, *refocilabis*, *saturabis*.

Es decir, su teoría es que es una palabra inventada que imitaba las formas del futuro que existían en latín para dar la impresión de ser una palabra culta. También cita una forma anterior, *miscolavis*, de la cual solo he podido encontrar una entrada en el *Terreros y Pando* de 1787:

> MISCOLAVIS, voz del ínfimo pueblo, lo mismo que un trago de vino.

De esta voz se derivaría *piscolabis*, con el mismo sentido de "un trago" pero extendido además a la comida, haciéndose sinónima por tanto de *tentempié*.